return type narrowing from array of predicates
classes with static check methods. wanted to find the
matching one and return to it in wrap method.
this architecture perfectly suits for my need of OOP-ifying.
here is the way that I used to do it in JavaScript:


class A {
    static check = arg => typeof arg == "number"
    constructor(arg) { this.value = arg}
    log = () => console.log("A/", this.value)
}

class B {
    static check = arg => typeof arg == "string"
    constructor(arg) { this.note = arg }
    log = () => console.log("B/", this.note)
}

function wrap(arg, classes) {
    for (const Class of classes) 
        if (Class.check(arg))
            return new Class(arg)
}

const classes = [A, B]

wrap("adaptive", classes).log()
wrap(999, classes).log()



lately, I thought maybe TypeScript could help me with that. what
I expected was that the wrap call would indicate the return
value (since it's all about types with no logic)
unfortunately, it was not the case. the closest I could get was that:
type PayloadA = number
type PayloadB = string
type PayloadGeneric = PayloadA | PayloadB

class A {
    static check(arg:PayloadGeneric): arg is PayloadA {
        return typeof arg == "number"
    }
    value: number
    constructor(arg: PayloadA) { this.value = arg}
    log = () => console.log("A/", this.value)
}

class B {
    static check(arg:PayloadGeneric): arg is PayloadB {
        return typeof arg == "string"
    }
    note: string
    constructor(arg: PayloadB) { this.note = arg}
    log = () => console.log("B/", this.note)
}

function wrap(arg: PayloadGeneric) {
    if (A.check(arg)) {   // understands that arg is number
        return new A(arg) // and that arg is suitable for PayloadA
    } 
    if (B.check(arg)) {   // understands that arg is string
        return new B(arg) // and that arg is suitable for PayloadB
    }
}

const instanceA = wrap(999) // but here it doesn't understand the type
const instanceB = wrap("adaptive") // neither here

(I know PayloadA and PayloadB may look silly since they're just
number and string but the whole point is about having custom interfaces
and predicates. number and string is just for the example and wrapping them
into a type demonstrates my purpouse better)
look wrap can only accept PayloadA or PayloadB. inside, we have 2 ifs.
one checks for PayloadA and understands and returns, the other checks
for PayloadB and again understands well and returns. but TypeScript
doesn't stop there and continues reading the rest, like it may get executed.
even thinks it may return undefined since I'm not handling the default
return, but logically, I do - I only accept A or B and handled both. so,
I'm handling all the cases but TypeScript doesn't get it. how do I fix it? I want something like return type narrowing.
and please don't tell me "just put return type A | B" I don't wanna hardcode
cuz the given list can change. I may put classes that none of their check method
matches, in this case I'd like to see that the return type is going to be undefined.
or I put one that matches, then I'd like to see what the return type is gonna be.
thanks in advance

Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

(pls see prev comment and edit accordingly) Assuming you want to use an array and return an appropriate conditional type, but you don't require that TS can "understand all the cases are handled" which is beyond TS's abilities, then you can maybe do it as shown in this playground link. Please test that out (thoroughly, please... it should work if you add elements to checkers) and let me know if it satisfies your use cases and you want to see it as an answer. If not, please include clarification in your [edit] about unmet use cases.

@jcalz I was prepared to tell you to post it as an answer so I accept it, but this case happened. I added class K which checks if the argument is equal to "k" and put it before B in the checkers but the outcome was horrible - calm lsp + crushed runtime

I had no idea you were using string literal types; you could do it this way I guess? Does that work? I can write up an answer if so (but you might want to edit that K class in your question if it's important to support)

doesn't work for the classic objects either. class J has an internal array which requires another checker class's predicate to be checked for every element of that array. see this. it's funnier cuz this time the compiler is mad but the runtime is okay :D

Look, I don't know how far down this rabbit hole you want me to follow you. Most of these issues have to do with type inference and you said that you want to allow someone passing in a payload that matches nothing and ends up producing undefined. If you are okay to require that the payload matches PayloadGeneric then it can serve as a hint as to how inference, possibly as shown in this playground link. But most of this is effectively outside the scope of your question as asked, and is more about playing whack-a-mole with type inference. How shall we proceed?

@jcalz I do appreciate the playgrounds. I was able to see the thing that I wanted, but not in the way I wanted. you see, it was not about just producing undefined. that's one aspect. I wanted to infer the type from predicates, which can be undefined. what I understand is that TS can't narrow it just from the types alone and I have to define types and the logic of them. your Check type is pretty much what to use at the moment. post a simple version as an answer.

If you have an array of such class constructors, like
const checkers = [A, B] as const;

then you can use it to at least express the intended call signature for wrap(), as a generic function that returns a conditional type:
type Check<T, C = typeof checkers> = C extends readonly [
    { check(arg: any): arg is infer P, new(arg: any): infer I }, ...infer R
] ? T extends P ? I : Check<T, R> : undefined;

declare function wrap<T extends PayloadGeneric | {} | null | undefined>(arg: T): Check<T>;

If you inspect the type Check<T> for generic T, you get:
type Z<T> = Check<T>;
// type Z<T> = T extends PayloadA ? A : T extends PayloadB ? B : undefined

So if you call wrap(arg) where arg is of type PayloadA, then the return type is A; otherwise, if you call it where arg is of type PayloadB, then the return type is B; otherwise the return type is undefined.  That gives the desired behavior, even if arg is of a union type:
const instanceA = wrap(999)
//    ^? const instanceA: A
console.log(instanceA.value.toFixed())

const instanceB = wrap("abc");
//    ^?
console.log(instanceB.note.toUpperCase());

const notInstance = wrap(new Date());
//    ^? const notInstance: undefined

const union = wrap(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 999 : new Date());
//    ^? const union: A | undefined

Note that the constraint on T in wrap() is PayloadGeneric | {} | null | undefined, which is effectively no constraint at all; it's a verbose way of expressing unknown. We don't really want to force callers of wrap() to pass in a PayloadGeneric (otherwise you'd never get undefined), so unknown is the intended constraint (note that if you do want to force such things then you can just make T extends PayloadGeneric, but then undefined is impossible)... but since the constraint includes PayloadGeneric it gives TypeScript a hint to interpret arg as a PayloadGeneric if possible. This handles cases where arg's type would normally be inferred differently (such as if arg is a string literal like "k", and you actually want the literal type "k" instead of the default string inferred). It's a complication that isn't really motivated by the question as asked, but can handle edge cases such as were raised in the comments. (That makes this section technically off-topic, but I'll leave it to hopefully minimize followup questions.)

So, it works as desired; let me briefly explain what Check<T> does:
type Check<T, C = typeof checkers> = C extends readonly [
    { check(arg: any): arg is infer P, new(arg: any): infer I }, ...infer R
] ? T extends P ? I : Check<T, R> : undefined;

This is a recursive conditional type that accepts two type arguments: the first is T, intended to be the type of arg in wrap(); the second is C, intended to be a tuple of "checker" class constructor types. (The const assertion in const checkers = ⋯ as const makes sure that checkers is a tuple type, so TypeScript knows the order of the elements.)
So Check<T, C> looks at the C tuple. If it has at least one element, then we look at its first element to infer the payload type P and the instance type I, and then the type we want is T extends P ? I : ⋯.  So if the first element is typeof A, then the type is T extends PayloadA ? A : ⋯. And in place of ⋯ we have the recursion Check<T, R> where R is the rest of the C tuple after the first element.  If C has no elements, then we have no more checkers left and the type evaluates to the base case of undefined.

Finally, to implement wrap():
function wrap<T extends PayloadGeneric | {} | null | undefined>(arg: T): Check<T>;
function wrap(arg: any) {
    for (const check of checkers) {
        if (check.check(arg)) {
            return new check(arg as never)
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

I've written this as a single-call-signature overload, in order to separate the strongly-typed call signature from the weakly-typed implementation. TypeScript is currently (and will probably always be) unable to verify that the loop inside the implementation satisfies the call signature. It's just too complicated; maybe it could be rewritten as a recursive function and when TypeScript 5.8 introduces microsoft/TypeScript#56941 there will be some way to write it with compiler-verified type safety, but even so it's probably not worth it.  By writing it as an overload, I've placed a barrier between call safety and implementation safety... and the implementation safety is our responsibility, not TypeScript's. If we're confident that it's written correctly, then we can just use whatever type assertions we need to get it compiling (arg as never, for example).

Playground link to code

awesome explanation! the word "never" is kinda bold tho. do you think loops for constant tuples would still be impossibly complex? or some stricter way of definition of the list? cuz to me it's like writing bunch of static ifs and when the function narrowing gets out it shouldn't be that hard. but I've barely got my hands on typescript so would like to hear you opinion

I don't understand what "when the function narrowing gets out it shouldn't be that hard" means. TypeScript isn't going to be able to look at a loop and unroll it; it cannot spend the resources analyzing the code in a loop by actually looping. Otherwise compilation would be simulation of all possible inputs which is mind bogglingly expensive except for the simplest of programs. So TS will either never do this, or you'd need some way to ask it to do so on an opt-in basis, but TS has generally rejected feature requests like that (e.g., https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051)

(see prev comment) The TS type checker isn't a human being, so any argument that looks like "this is obvious to me so it should be obvious to TS" is flawed. You'd need to identify some specific functionality implemented in TS to argue why it should be verifying something and not appeal to human intuition about equivalence.

for me the part that's a bit unclear is the argument being the performance for loops. I mean yeah it is some work, but isn't it the same with recursion? I'd say it's even heavier assuming it'll has a stack and stuff. wouldn't doing it with a "flat loop" be faster?

Both loops and recursion are more expensive than a single pass, which is how TS analyzes the code. I’m not prepared to go into much detail in these comments about the compiler performance concerns so if you still have followup questions you might want to make a new post.

honestly I'm afraid to make a post to discuss about programming in stackoverflow. did a research, couldn't find a way, decided to post a question about way to integrate my js architecture to ts types. explained the problem detailed, with minimal examples and stuff, yet it has negative vote :(

‍♂️ Yeah, I don't know what to say about downvotes. I rarely downvote until someone demonstrates unwillingness to improve or allow improvement to their post.

TS currently doesn't support following control flow to infer a narrowed return type. The situation will change with TS 5.8 to some degree. As a current solution you could try function overloading:
Playground
function wrap(arg: PayloadA): A;
function wrap(arg: PayloadB): B;
function wrap(arg: PayloadGeneric)  {
    if (A.check(arg)) {   // understands that arg is number
        return new A(arg) // and that arg is suitable for PayloadA
    } 
    if (B.check(arg)) {   // understands that arg is string
        return new B(arg) // and that arg is suitable for PayloadB
    }
    throw new Error('arg is not of allowed type string|number')
}


thanks for the playground example! function overloading is a great workaround. almost all I wanted except it I can't use a dynamic array and I have to explicitly hardcode every matching return type.
